# Updating Visual Studio .csproj new Method

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application i am using the following code to update my `.csproj`.

```
var project = new Project();
project.Load(path);
var itemGroup = project.AddNewItemGroup();
var buildItem = itemGroup.AddNewItem("ProjectReference",@"..\Basics\Test.csproj");
buildItem.SetMetadata("Project","sf34-34hg-jgjk3-3434-99345345hh345");
buildItem.SetMetadata("Name","Test");
project.Save(path,Encoding.UTF8);
```

The code is working fine. But during the time of compilation. It shows a warning like `Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project is Obsolete` which is advising to use another assembly `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.`

I searched for changing the code with new assembly, but didn't get much information on the same. Anyone please help me to change this code to new method.

Comment: Maybe on the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.ASPX)?

Comment: A simple search for `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project` returns the documentation page